# Emails sent via a Rules action contain arbitrary line breaks

Tags: rules, emails

I have an email sent by Rules. Here is the text of the email in the Rules action:

> Welcome to x! As a professional user, you can now showcase your
>   business on x by creating a Professional Profile and uploading photos
>   of your best x.

Here is what the user gets (note line breaks):

> ```
> Welcome to x! As a professional user, you can now showcase your
> business
> on x by creating a Professional Profile and uploading photos of your
> best x.
> ```

I'm not sure why there are arbitrary line breaks being inserted in the text when sent via email. I've excluded the RTE on email field in the rule, and included only plain text.

Comment: It's possible the actual text being stored as a `\r\n` somewhere in it. Try retyping the text (no copy and paste).

Comment: @kylex - Thanks for your note. I retyped the message and confirmed the issue persists.

Answer (score 5):

You are most likely up against the hard limit of line length (77) for plain text emails, defined in a Drupal core function `_drupal_wrap_mail_line`. It quotes [RFC 3676](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3676.txt) as the reason for this.

If you want the one line of text you might be able to do it using a HTML formatted email rather than plain text. Alternatively you may want to reformat your email so it suits the available width. The third option of altering core or making a plugin to let you make long lined emails is probably a little overboard.